# How to get time while querying in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

How can I write this rails query in proper SQL query ?

```
time = (Time.now - 1.days).beginning_of_day
Assignment.where("created_at >= :time OR updated_at >= :time", time: time).pluck(:assignable_id).uniq
```

Can you help me to convert this in SQL Query ?

```
select distinct assignable_id from assignments where created_at >= getDate() && updated_at >= getDate();
```

I need help in how to get date while querying?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date using MySQL using `CURDATE()`.

Your query would look like this:

```sql
select distinct assignable_id from assignments where created_at >= CURDATE() AND updated_at >= CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use inequality comparison directly using just ActiveRecord, you will have to use Arel that is a lower level api that ActiveRecord is built on. Luckily you can mix and match them most of the time.

```rb
time = (Time.now - 1.days).beginning_of_day
assignments = Assignment.arel_table
Assignment.where(
  assignments[:created_at].gteq(time).or(assignments[:updated_at].gteq(time))
).distinct.pluck(:assignable_id)
```

Passing the current date in from ruby code is a good solution most of the time. However if you do want to use database functions, then Arel is here to help again.

```rb
time = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('getDate', [])
# or
time = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('CURDATE', [])
# or any other function you can think of
```

Arel does seem more complicated than just writing raw sql at first glance, but the key is reusability and safety. Arel snippets are easy to reuse by just making them into methods. It's also easy to make injection mistakes using raw sql, Arel will prevent you from making those in most™️ cases.